# pytest.raises Failed: DID NOT RAISE with try/except

Tags: python, pytest

When using pytest.raises to test an error that is caught by a try/except block, it fails due to it not being raised.

If I do a simple test with a dict lookup and don't put a try/except around it, the pytest.raises test passes.  But if try/except is used, the test fails.

This is what works:

```
def lookup_value(key):

    lookup = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}

    return lookup[key]


def test_lookup():

    with pytest.raises(KeyError):
        lookup_value('C')
```

Now add the try/except:

```
def lookup_value(key):

    lookup = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}

    try:
        return lookup[key]
    except KeyError as err:
        print(err)


def test_lookup():

    with pytest.raises(KeyError):
        lookup_value('C')
```

First snippet, test passes.
Second snippet, I get "Failed: DID NOT RAISE `<class 'KeyError'`>"

Comment: That's exactly what should happen - `pytest.raises` will fail the test if the expected exception is not raised.

Comment: Uh-huh-huh (Beavis).  Sorry. I guess I better re-think how the test passes with a successful raise instead of it failing if it's done properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code here is swallowing the exception (catching it without propagating the fact that an exception occured).

```
    try:
        return lookup[key]
    except KeyError as err:
        print(err)
```

You just need to reraise the exception so that `pytest.raises` will see it

```
    try:
        return lookup[key]
    except KeyError as err:
        print(err)
        raise
```

Also, it's generally bad practice to omit a `return` statement at the end of a function that returns something in another code path. In Python there is an implied `return None` but why not help the reader out a little by writing it explicitly.

Comment: OK thanks - I never knew I had to re-raise again in every except block.

Comment: Would you say it's standard practice to reraise in except blocks?  I guess I'm finding this out because I'm really trying to force myself to do TDD.

Comment: No, I'd say it's rare.  I don't remember what the pattern is called, but errors should generally be handled only once, in the place where it makes sense to handle them.  In your example, you're handling the error twice - once in the function (with the print call), and then once in the caller (by reraising the exception).  You can consider if that extra print call adds any value, or if you just let the calling function deal with the error how it sees fit.  Or the caller's calling function, or the caller's callers' calling etc...